# Uncaught ReferenceError: BigText is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, expand

I am using the [BigText library](https://github.com/DanielHoffmann/jquery-bigtext/) to expand text inside my divs.

I have copied the file on my webserver and included it as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/imgLiquid-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fullpage/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fullpage/examples.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-bigtext.js"></script>
<script src="../js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({

          var bt = BigText.noConflict(true);
            $.fn.bt = bt.jQueryMethod;
            $('.referencesProductHeader').bigtext();

    });

</script>
```

When running the code I get the issue:

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (jquery-bigtext.js)

Why should there be a syntax error? I just have copied the file.

And the issue:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: BigText is not defined.

What am I doing wrong? I have followed the steps of the samples...

Comment: You have syntax error in `jquery-bigtext.js`, nothing we can really help you on...

Comment: Seems like a really weird way to use the `bigtext` plugin, with the noConflict and overwriting the plugin with a property of the original plugin etc ?

Comment: I have copied the files from the official homepage

Comment: though you copied files, but still something is missing. please go through some documentation/tutorial first.

Comment: What happens when you navigate your browser to js/jquery-bigtext.js ? Maybe the file's not there or has some weird permissions and the server returns an error page (404 or 403) instead of the file contents? This would explain the Unexpected Token error.

Comment: the file exists in the filesystem and I am able to open it without problems. I can access it finder and with the web server without any problem.